# LayoutManager for RecyclerView Grid with different cell width in android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

[image]

StaggeredGridLayoutManager doesn't seem to allow customizing a cell width or span multiple columns (except full span) for vertical orientation.

How to create a layout like the above image? What will be the perfect Layout Manager in this case... GridLayoutManager or StaggeredGridLayoutManager?

Answer (score 6):

Instead of using `StaggeredGridLayoutManager` you can use `GridLayoutManager`. To have different column count in row you have to override [setSpanSizeLookup](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/GridLayoutManager.html?hl=ru#setSpanSizeLookup(android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup)).

Example:

```
GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getAppContext(), spanCount);
gridLayoutManager.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
    @Override
    public int getSpanSize(int position) {
        //define span size for this position
        //for example, if you have 2 column per row, you can implement something like that:
        if(position == youRule) {
            return 2; //item will take 2 column (full row size)
        } else {
            return 1; //you will have 2 rolumn per row
        }
    }
});
```

Pay attention that `spanSize` <= `spanCount`

Comment: I have already tried that but failed to get exact output. Here is my code:   `GridLayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 3);
        layoutManager.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
            @Override
            public int getSpanSize(int position) {
                if (position % 2 == 0) {
                    return 2;
                } else {
                    return 1;
                }
//                return (3 - position % 3);
            }
        });`

Answer (score 1):

Well, I have solved it! The solution is:-

```
GridLayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 2);
        layoutManager.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
            @Override
            public int getSpanSize(int position) {
//                if (position % 3 == 0) {
//                    Log.e("TAG", "Position: " + position +" position % 3= " + position % 3 + " return 2");
//                    return 2;
//                } else {
//                    Log.e("TAG", "Position: " + position +" position % 3= " + position % 3 + " return 1");
//                    return 1;
//                }
                if (position % 3 == 0 || position % 3 == 1) {
                    Log.e("TAG", "Position: " + position +" position % 3= " + position % 3 + " return 1");
                    return 1;
                } else {
                    Log.e("TAG", "Position: " + position +" position % 3= " + position % 3 + " return 2");
                    return 2;
                }
//                return (3 - position % 3);
            }
        });
```